# Flutter Google sheets FormatException:Unexpected character (at character 1)<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.co

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets

I want to get data from my flutter app and show it on google sheets. The code doesn't show any error and i have checked also my code...Also deployed the google sheets on the script editor. still when i call the function while using the app it gives me this error:  `I/flutter (23770): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) I/flutter (23770): <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.co... I/flutter (23770): ^` and no data shows on google sheets.

Google sheets script editor code:

```
function myFunction(request) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1...E');
  var result = {"status": "SUCCESS"};

  try{
    var email = request.parameter.email;
    var userid = request.parameter.userid;
    var type = request.parameter.type;
    var reports = request.parameter.reports;

    var rowData = sheet.appendRow([email, userid, type, reports]);

  } catch(exc) {
    result = {"status": "FAILED", "message": exc}
  }

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

My model code:

```
class ReportDb{
  String email;
  String userid;
  String type;
  String reports;

  ReportDb(this.email, this.userid, this.type, this.reports);

  String toParams() => "?email=$email&userid=$userid&type=$type&reports=$reports";

}
```

controller code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:jagu_meet/sever_db/report_abuse/report_db.dart';

class ReportServerController {
  final void Function(String) callback;

  static const String URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/......./exec";
  static const STATUS_SUCCESS = "SUCCESS";

  ReportServerController(this.callback);

  void submitAbuseData(ReportDb reportDb) async {
    try {
      await http.get(
          Uri.parse( URL + reportDb.toParams())
      ).then((response) {
        callback(convert.jsonDecode(response.body)['status']);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  }
}
```

Execution: calling the following function:

```
void _submitAbuseData(String email, String userid, String type, String reports,) {
    ReportDb reportDb  = ReportDb(email, userid, type, reports);

    ReportServerController reportServerController = ReportServerController(
            (String response) {
          print(response);
        }
    );
    reportServerController.submitAbuseData(reportDb);
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the response body you're receiving is JSON and not HTML? I advise you check with a debugger.

Comment: I/flutter (23770): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) I/flutter (23770): <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.co... I/flutter (23770): ^ :- am getting this error while running in debug mode...and i have not tested in relaese mode.

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of the returned response.body, it shows that it is an HTML page. You get a FormatException error because the format you are expecting is a JSON object. You could print the response.body on debug console to see the message or the web page. From there, we can properly troubleshoot your problem.